# Aol Contact API

Tags: xml, api

Aol contact API.
Hello can any body please tell me how to fetch complete contacts address book(including buddy name,phone number,emails etc.). I'm getting this sort of information while using following query using curl:

### Query:-

$aimStartUrl = "http://api.oscar.aol.com/presence/get?f=xml&bl=1&k=".$devId."&a=". urlencode($authToken);

### Getting result :-

```
<groups>
 <group>
  <name>picopico</name>
  <buddies>
    <buddy>
     <aimId>mundufive</aimId>
     <displayId>mundufive</displayId>
     <state>offline</state>
     <userType>aim</userType>
     <presenceIcon>http://o.aolcdn.com/aim/img/offline.gif</presenceIcon>
   </buddy>
 </buddies>
</group>
```

### Expected result:-

Complete xml (consisting of buddy name,phone number,emails etc.)

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [XML-Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Parser) Perl module.

Comment: hello ,thanx for your reponse i think you didnt understand my question..i m not getting complete xml as a response calling aol contact api.parsing is secondary thing first we need complete xml