# AOL contacts API

Tags: aol

Is anybody aware of any AOL API (e.g. based on OAuth) that would expose the user address book (no screen-scraping)?

I've seen a few threads about it but no answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923106/does-aol-have-a-contacts-api
- [Aol Contact API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909248/aol-contact-api)

Answer (score 3):

AOL has been promising this feature for a while: http://dev.aol.com/api/addressbook/comingsoon

There doesn't seen to have been any activity on this front for a long time. I'd also really like to know if AOL is intending to add this feature anytime soon.

Edit: AOL has changed their developer site and there is no longer a mention of the Contacts API.